# Swift 3: Passing Data From TabBarController to Child View Controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, tabbarcontroller

I am trying to create an iOS app that contains login logic by using a custom "User" class that holds all of the information needed by the app for a particular user. My app also has a tab bar controller for the main interface. However, I am having a hard time figuring out the best approach on how to pass the logged in "User" from the login screen to the tab bar controller and then to the corresponding child view controllers. Please note I also need a navigation controller for each of my tabs. My current logic is as follows:

**LoginViewController.swift:**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    func displayRideFinishedSurvey(loggedInUser: User) -> Void { //user provided valid credentials, time to login
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "SuccessfulLogin", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let cc = (sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarStoryboard")) as! MyTabBarController
        cc.loggedInUser = loggedInUser // will be configured here for the entire app
        present(cc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**MyTabBarController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var loggedInUser: User?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**MyAccountViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class MyAccountViewController: UIViewController {

    var loggedInUser: User?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**A screenshot can be seen below to represent the storyboard setup: (There are multiple tabs, just an example)**

[image]

**With the information provided: What would be the best approach to setting the "loggedInUser" variable within MyAccountViewController?**

Answer (score 0):

Several options:
1.Use NSUserDefault to persist the data into storage.
2.Create a singleton.
3.Global variable
You can choose whatever you want.

Comment: Which of the above options do you believe is the most professional/efficient?

Comment: @JustinFrazer I think the easiest way is creating a public var in child view controllers class. Before showing the child view controller, set the var accordingly.